# Showing suspended (right-censored) data points in diagram (distributed on x-axis)

Tags: data-visualization, weibull-distribution

How is it possible to show the suspended (right-censored) datapoints (distributed on x-axis without value for y-axis) in e.g. Probability Plot - Weibull CDF like the green triangles in attached image?

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please see update from 18. Jan. 23